# How to filter by dateHour on Google Analytics API?

Tags: api, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to retrieve results from the Google Analytics API that are between two specific dateHours. I tried to use the following filter:

```
'filters' => 'ga:dateHour>2013120101;ga:dateHour<2013120501'
```

But this doesn't work. What do I need to do? (I've used other filters before, and they work just fine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you're trying to use greater than and less than on a dimension which doesn't work. Dimension filters only allow ==, !=, =@, !@,=~, and !=.

So, if you want to get ga:dateHour, you'll have to use a regex filter:

```
ga:dateHour=~^2013120([1-4][0-2][0-9]|500)$;ga:dateHour!~^201312010[0-1]$
```

EDIT:
I wouldn't hesitate a second to learn RegEx, especially if you're a programmer. Here is a great SO post on [learning regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions).

So, to break it down:

```
=~ looking to match the following regex
!= not looking to match the following regex
```

(check out [GA's filter operators](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#q_summary))

`^` at the start of a string

`2013120` since the entire dateHour range contained this string of numbers, look for that

`([1-4][0-2][0-9]|500)` match every number after `2013120`, so the first `[1-4]` will match `20131201`, `20131202`, `20131203`, and `20131204`, then within those strings we want the next number to be `[0-2]` and likewise with `[0-9]`. So look at each [ ] as a placeholder for a range of digits.

`|` means or

`500` says, we only want `500` and nothing more, so it's very specific.

The whole statement is wrapped in `()` so we can say he, match `[1-4][0-2][0-9]` OR `500`, after `2013120`.

Then, we end it with `$` to signify the end of the string.

This probably isn't the most concise way to describe how this filter is working, but what I would do is use a website like [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) or some other regex testing tool, and get the range you'd like to filter and start writing regex.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Blexy, it works. Do you mind giving a quick explanation of the regex you're using? I don't fully understand it. I'm asking because I'll have to filter for various different dateHours and would need to be able to edit the regex.